# How to make json decimal round to three digits

Tags: python, json

I have the following list of list:

```
x = [["foo",3.923239],["bar",1.22333]]
```

What I want to do is to convert the numeric value into 3 digits under JSON string.
Yielding

```
myjsonfinal = "[["foo", 3.923], ["bar", 1.223]]"
```

I tried this but failed:

```
import json
print json.dumps(x)
```

Ideally we'd like this to be fast because need to deal with ~1000 items. Then load to web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@neversaint, Try this:

```
x = [["foo", 3.923239], ["bar", 1.22333]]

for i, j in enumerate(x):
    x[i][1] = round(j[1], 3)

print x
```

Output:

```
[['foo', 3.923], ['bar', 1.223]]
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Any reason for enumerate? `for subseq in seq` should word just fine.

Comment: No just to have better control over list iteration. `for key, value in list` is fine as well!

Comment: Thats not "better control". It's counter-intuitive (unpythonic) and superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

Try `round()`

```
import json
x = [["foo",3.923239],["bar",1.22333]]
json.dumps([[s, round(i, 3)] for s, i in x])
```